# How can I make this LINQ search method handle more than two terms?

Tags: c#, linq

The following search method **works** **fine** for up to **two** terms.

**How can I make it dynamic so that it is able to handle any number of search terms?**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestContains82343
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> tasks = new List<string>();
            tasks.Add("Add contract to Customer.");
            tasks.Add("New contract for customer.");
            tasks.Add("Create new contract.");
            tasks.Add("Go through the old contracts.");
            tasks.Add("Attach files to customers.");

            var filteredTasks = SearchListWithSearchPhrase(tasks, "contract customer");

            filteredTasks.ForEach(t => Console.WriteLine(t));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static List<string> SearchListWithSearchPhrase(List<string> tasks, string searchPhrase)
        {
            string[] parts = searchPhrase.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            List<string> searchTerms = new List<string>();
            foreach (string part in parts)
            {
                searchTerms.Add(part.Trim());
            }

            switch (searchTerms.Count())
            {
                case 1:
                    return (from t in tasks
                            where t.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerms[0].ToUpper()) 
                            select t).ToList();
                case 2:
                    return (from t in tasks
                            where t.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerms[0].ToUpper()) && t.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerms[1].ToUpper())
                            select t).ToList();
                default:
                    return null;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about replacing

```
switch (searchTerms.Count())
{
    case 1:
        return (from t in tasks
                where t.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerms[0].ToUpper())
                select t).ToList();
    case 2:
        return (from t in tasks
                where t.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerms[0].ToUpper()) && t.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerms[1].ToUpper())
                select t).ToList();
    default:
        return null;
}
```

By

```
(from t in tasks
 where searchTerms.All(term => t.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper()))
 select t).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just call `Where` repeatedly... I've changed the handling of `searchTerms` as well to make this slightly more LINQ-y :)

```
public static List<string> SearchListWithSearchPhrase
    (List<string> tasks, string searchPhrase)
{
    IEnumerable<string> searchTerms = searchPhrase.Split(' ')
                                                  .Select(x => x.Trim());
    IEnumerable<string> query = tasks;
    foreach (string term in searchTerms)
    {
        // See edit below
        String captured = term;
        query = query.Where(t => t.ToUpper().Contains(captured));
    }
    return query.ToList();
}
```

You should note that by default, `ToUpper()` will be culture-sensitive - there are various caveats about case-insensitive matching :( Have a look at [this guidance on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973919.aspx) for more details. I'm not sure how much support there is for case-insensitive `Contains` though :(

EDIT: I like konamiman's answer, although it looks like it's splitting somewhat differently to your original code. [`All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) is definitely a useful LINQ operator to know about...

Here's how I would write it though:

```
return tasks.Where(t => searchTerms.All(term => t.ToUpper().Contains(term)))
            .ToList();
```

(I don't generally use a query expression when it's a single operator applied to the outer query.)

EDIT: Aargh, I can't believe I fell into the [captured variable issue](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) :( You need to create a copy of the `foreach` loop variable as otherwise the closure will always refer to the "current" value of the variable... which will always be the *last* value by the time `ToList` is executed :(

EDIT: Note that everything so far is inefficient in terms of uppercasing each task several times. That's probably fine in reality, but you *could* avoid it by using something like this:

```
IEnumerable<string> query = tasks.Select
    (t => new { Original = t, Upper = t.ToUpper });
return query.Where(task => searchTerms.All(term => task.Upper.Contains(term)))
            .Select(task => task.Original)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: For case insensitve contains you might want to check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring

Answer (score 1):

Can't test code right now, but you could do something similar to this:

```
from t in tasks
let taskWords=t.ToUpper().Split(new char[] { ' ' });
where searchTerms.All(term => taskWords.Contains(term.ToUpper()))
select t
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the switch statement with a for loop :)

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestSearch()
    {
        List<string> tasks = new List<string>
            {
                "Add contract to Customer.",
                "New contract for customer.",
                "Create new contract.",
                "Go through the old contracts.",
                "Attach files to customers."
            };

        var filteredTasks = SearchListWithSearchPhrase(tasks, "contract customer new");

        filteredTasks.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
    }

    public static List<string> SearchListWithSearchPhrase(List<string> tasks, string searchPhrase)
    {
        var query = tasks.AsEnumerable();

        foreach (var term in searchPhrase.Split(new[] { ' ' }))
        {
            string s = term.Trim();
            query = query.Where(x => x.IndexOf(s, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1);
        }

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use a foreach and AddRange() after splitting the terms and saving it into a list.

```
List<ItemsImLookingFor> items = new List<ItemsImLookingFor>();

// search for terms
foreach(string term in searchTerms)
{
   // add users to list
   items.AddRange(dbOrList(
         item => item.Name.ToLower().Contains(str)).ToList()
   );
}
```

that should work for any amount of terms.