# Does LINQ have any built-in search which supports search-machine-like searching?

Tags: c#, linq, search

If I have a `List<string>` and want to do a standard search through it, I can use a LINQ statement like this:

```
(from t in tasks
 where searchTerms.All(term => t.ToUpper().Contains(term.ToUpper()))
 select t).ToList();
```

But if I want to support standard search-engine-like syntax to handle phrases such as:

```
contract
contract customer
jim customer
"Jim Smith" customer
```

then I need to start rolling my own **custom** search method. In addition as [Jon Skeet mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1866018/how-can-i-make-this-linq-search-method-handle-more-than-two-terms/1866040#1866040), you have to be careful with comparing with ToUpper() with different **culture** settings, and if you are in a web environment, you have many issues with **encoding** and searching-for-encoded-characters issues, etc.

**Is there not a .NET or LINQ solution which handles search-machine-like searches, e.g. instead of Contains() something like ConstainsSearchTerms()?**

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LINQ2SQL, you can use the `SqlMethods.Like` methods to generate a LIKE like used in SQL.

Else on LINQ2Objects, just use regex.

Regarding `ToUpper`. This is problematic, the better solution is to use string case folding, but unfortunately .NET only supports the simple model  :(

Answer (score 0):

It's not LINQ, but you may want to look into [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/). It actually is a search engine, and a pretty good one, too.